# Locations equidistant from three points on a sphere

Tags: spherical-geometry

A group friends is now split in three different cities on earth. They want to meet anywhere equidistant from all three cities. Where can that be ? The three cities happen to be Paris (France), Stuttgart and Munich (Germany). Where does that actually land ?

Charles

Comment: Assuming a spherical earth, take the great circles bisecting Paris and Stuttgart and bisecting Stuttgart and Munich.  These great circles meet in two points (I think one a long way south and the other possibly in the Pacific) which are equidistant from the three cities.  They would all save a lot of time meeting somewhere like Stuttgart, Nancy, Metz, Strasbourg or Basle

Comment: The three given cities are almost collinear. They'd be best off meeting in _Nancy_.